# How do I record my screen on one space and work on another?

Tags: screen-capture, spaces

QuickTime Player allows you to easily record your screen on macOS. However, neither does it seem to allow to record a specific window nor can I record in a different space than I am currently working on (it will only record a specific part of the screen that is in view).

Is there any reasonable (preferably free and light-weight) alternative to achieve this?

Comment: Best guess - I'll let someone else confirm - you are recording, in effect, a GPU intercept, so if your GPU isn't drawing it, you can't capture it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think that's an answer but I don't have anything to back it up, only that the `-l` window choice offered by `screencapture` is ignored when adding `-v` for video recording.